# Multiple python append functions in while loop crashing

Tags: python, list, while-loop, append

Attempting to print a composite list by appending item from three smaller lists in sequence:

```
def final_xyz_lister():
    global final_xyz_list
    final_xyz_list = []
    step=0
    while step==0:
        final_xyz_list.append(carbon_final_list[step]) 
        final_xyz_list.append(oxygen_final_list[step]) 
        final_xyz_list.append(hydrogen_final_list[step]) 
        step=+1
    while 0 < step < 50:   
        final_xyz_list.append(carbon_final_list[step]) 
        final_xyz_list.append(oxygen_final_list[step]) 
        final_xyz_list.append(hydrogen_final_list[step]) 
        step=+1
    else:
        pass
```

If I comment out the second while loop the first element of the list is printed in a list as expected but introduction of the second while loop results in a MemoryError.

Comment: Could you give us the complete error?

Comment: As an aside, your function should return `final_xyz_list` instead of trying to make it global.

Comment: `step=+1` `-->` `step+=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to append the three items in 2 different while loops. It would also be simpler if you used for loops. in this case:

```
for step in range(0, 50):
    final_xyz_list.append(carbon_final_list[step]) 
    final_xyz_list.append(oxygen_final_list[step]) 
    final_xyz_list.append(hydrogen_final_list[step])
```

Edit: Also, I just noticed the error, you use `step =+ 1`, which is the same as saying `step = +1` or `step = 1`. This is why you are getting a memory error, you keep defining step as 1, which is between 0 and 50, so the while loop just keeps going. what you probbly wanted to write was `step += 1`, this increases step by 1 and doesn't set it to 1

Comment: Will using a for loop instead of a while loop fix the MemoryError problem?

Comment: I don't know, I would try it out. Maybe you don't have enough ram for the program (which I doubt since it's not that demanding)